# not selector, on() click event not working

Tags: jquery

I have my HTML as so

```
<tr class="show_ticket_preview">
    <td>
         <a class="ticket_preview_id">A Link</a>
         <p>Some other stuf</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to trigger the click event when the `tr` is clicked but not when a `<a>` is clicked in the `tr`

```
$(document).on('click', '.show_ticket_preview:not(.ticket_preview_id)', function() {
```

but for whatever reason the event is still triggering when I click on `ticket_preview_id` based on my code above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.show_ticket_preview:not(.ticket_preview_id)` selector will select all elements that has class `show_ticket_preview` but not has class `ticket_preview_id` so it's not working in your case.

To solve your problem, you can use event object in the handle then check if the target has class `ticket_preview_id` or not:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.show_ticket_preview', function(e) {
  if(!e.target.classList.contains("ticket_preview_id")) console.log(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show_ticket_preview">
    <div>
         <a class="ticket_preview_id">A Link</a>
         <p>Some other stuf</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have another click event which is tied to the `ticket_preview_id` and make use of the `stopPropagation` method.

```
$(document).on('click', '.show_ticket_preview', function() {
    // Do Something
})

$(document).on('click', '.ticket_preview_id', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

You can see more about stopPropagation here... https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/